Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'U' despite both T and U are same when calling function
I know this question is already been asked here on StackOverflow and GitHub. In this question, I want to extend their conversation. As typescript core team member RyanCavanaugh said:

Everything described so far is the intended behavior. Not inferring union types from disparate candidates is 100% intentional; this doesn't yield expected results in a huge majority of cases even though it can be theoretically justified.

But using a trick I managed to make both types a and b as same. But still typescript is not able to figure out both a and b would be the same.
type Addable = string | number
type BeSame<T>= T extends number ? number : string
function addMe<T extends Addable,U extends BeSame<T>>(a: T,b: U) {
    return a+b;
}

-Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'U'

Expected Behaviour:
Since I'm telling typescript both a and b type would be the same it should allow me to use + operator on a and b.
addMe("helo", 2); // error cuz a and b are not same
addMe(4,5); // fine a and b are same
addMe("hello", "hello"); // also fine



TS isn't a proof solver, it can't understand arbitrary "tricks" and conclude things from it. So this is going to be a fundamental TS limitation. Furthermore, we can't conclude anything from your "trick" because it's not true: you can call addMe(Math.random() < 0.99 ? "hello" : 123, 456) without a compiler error and have a 99% chance of adding a string to a number. • Given these facts, I don't see how this question is meaningfully distinct from the one you linked above. I'm inclined to close it as a duplicate, unless you have some more information not shown here.
